# Unable to load class when on live environment in laravel

Tags: php, class, laravel

I am new to the Laravel framework so please be easy on me!

I have developed an application where I use a Helper class for some handy functions such as generating a slug from a string. I have created a helper.php class in a classes folder in my app directory, then in my global.php file I have added the classes folder to the "ClassLoader".

You can see my setup as follows:

Site Structure

```
-site
  -app
    -classes
       -helpers.php
    -controllers
```

global.php

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/classes', 
));
```

helpers.php

```
class Helpers {

    public static function slug($url_to_encode) {
        $slug = urlencode($url_to_encode);
        $slug = preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9]++~i', '-', $slug); $slug = trim($slug, '-'); 
        return $slug;
    }

}
```

Everything works fine on my local Mac testing environment and I can call my "slug" helper function with no problems.

```
$slug = Helpers::slug($article->name);
```

The problem I have is when I move my site onto my live server, everything part of my application works great apart from pages where I call my "Helpers" class.

The site breaks and I receive the following error message:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Helpers' not found
```

[image]

I am a little confused as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Sidenote, you know the're a slug() method in the Str class? `Str::slug()` Also, what environment is your live server?

Comment: I didn't know that! Great to know for the future. I also have quite a few other helpers so it would be good to find out why this class isn't loading but the Str::slug() is good to know.

Local I am running MAMP, PHP 5.4.4

Live I am running Linux, Centos 6.4, Plesk, apache with PHP 5.4.4

Comment: Run `composer.phar dump-autoload` or `composer dump-autoload` and let us know what happens.

Comment: Do you mean on my Live environment? I will give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: When I run composer dump-autoload I get "Generating autoload files" but I am doing this on my local environment. Am I correct in thinking I can use the composer loading commands on my local version and then upload the result to my server? This would be my preferred method. Thanks.

Comment: You *should* be able to, yes.  I'd still try the dump on your live environment, though.  There's obviously something different between your local and live environments, and this is the first place I go.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use composer autoloader directly instead of laravel's; so in your case it would be.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
            "app/classes",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",

    ]
},
```

in your composer.json file at the root of the project, then run composer dump-autoload or php artisan dump-autoload on your production server through ssh, if you don't have ssh access just dump-autoload on your local machine, test and then transfer the files.